# AudioSessionSetProperty is Depreceted in ios7. How to set kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

UInt32 bt = FALSE;
  AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput , sizeof(UInt32), &bt);

Using above code i am trying to turn on audio from Bluetooth which not working currently.

Any suggestion ?